# how to fix Nemo models restore_path error

Tags: python

this error occurs when `restore_from` with `.nemo`  files.

```bash
`asr_model = nemo_asr.models.EncDecCTCModelBPE.restore_from(
            restore_path=os.path.join(MODELS_URL, "stt_en_conformer_ctc_xlarge.nemo"),
            map_location=device,
)`
```

I tried restore_path with this code. But this occurs this error:

```bash
not a gzip file
```

and

```bash
Could not load English CTC model
[NeMo I 2024-01-03 15:43:46 tokenizer_utils:125] Getting HuggingFace AutoTokenizer with pretrained_model_name: bert-base-uncased, vocab_file: /tmp/tmpy2yvwun8/tokenizer.vocab_file, special_tokens_dict: {}, and use_fast: False
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 modelPT:135] If you intend to do training or fine-tuning, please call the ModelPT.setup_training_data() method and provide a valid configuration file to setup the train data loader.
    Train config : 
    use_tarred_dataset: false
    label_info_save_dir: null
    text_file: text_train.txt
    labels_file: labels_train.txt
    tokens_in_batch: null
    max_seq_length: 128
    num_samples: -1
    use_cache: true
    cache_dir: null
    get_label_frequences: false
    verbose: true
    n_jobs: 0
    tar_metadata_file: null
    tar_shuffle_n: 1
    shuffle: true
    drop_last: false
    pin_memory: true
    num_workers: 8
    persistent_workers: true
    ds_item: punct_dataset_complete
    
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 modelPT:142] If you intend to do validation, please call the ModelPT.setup_validation_data() or ModelPT.setup_multiple_validation_data() method and provide a valid configuration file to setup the validation data loader(s). 
    Validation config : 
    use_tarred_dataset: false
    label_info_save_dir: null
    text_file: text_dev.txt
    labels_file: labels_dev.txt
    tokens_in_batch: null
    max_seq_length: 128
    num_samples: -1
    use_cache: true
    cache_dir: null
    get_label_frequences: false
    verbose: true
    n_jobs: 0
    tar_metadata_file: null
    tar_shuffle_n: 1
    shuffle: true
    drop_last: false
    pin_memory: true
    num_workers: 8
    persistent_workers: true
    ds_item: punct_dataset_complete
    
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 modelPT:148] Please call the ModelPT.setup_test_data() or ModelPT.setup_multiple_test_data() method and provide a valid configuration file to setup the test data loader(s).
    Test config : 
    use_tarred_dataset: false
    label_info_save_dir: null
    text_file: text_dev.txt
    labels_file: labels_dev.txt
    tokens_in_batch: null
    max_seq_length: 128
    num_samples: -1
    use_cache: true
    cache_dir: null
    get_label_frequences: false
    verbose: true
    n_jobs: 0
    tar_metadata_file: null
    tar_shuffle_n: 1
    shuffle: true
    drop_last: false
    pin_memory: true
    num_workers: 8
    persistent_workers: true
    ds_item: punct_dataset_complete
    
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 nlp_overrides:208] Apex was not found. Please see the NeMo README for installation instructions: https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo#megatron-gpt.
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 modelPT:1088] World size can only be set by PyTorch Lightning Trainer.
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 nlp_model:63] Apex was not found. Please see the NeMo README for installation instructions: https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo#megatron-gpt.
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 punctuation_capitalization_model:681] The artifact `class_labels.punct_labels_file` was not found in checkpoint. Will rely on `punct_label_ids` parameter
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 punctuation_capitalization_model:703] The artifact `class_labels.capit_labels_file` was not found in checkpoint. Will rely on `capit_label_ids` parameter
[NeMo W 2024-01-03 15:43:47 modelPT:202] You tried to register an artifact under config key=tokenizer.vocab_file but an artifact for it has already been registered.
Error(s) in loading state_dict for PunctuationCapitalizationModel:
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "bert_model.embeddings.position_ids". 
Could not load English NLP model
not a gzip file
Could not load Russian CTC model
not a gzip file
Could not load Russian NLP model
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

how to fix this error ???

I re-download .nemo models from official website Nemo Models
But it still throw that error,

Comment: SOLUTION : must install compatible versions ex:versions of (python, torch, torchvision, nemo, ffmpeg....). 
See NeMo official from (Github)[https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo] here showed all dependencies